# Как связать чек бокс со строкой напротив которой он находится

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Доброго времени суток! Есть таблица и есть проблема, не могу сообразить как связать чек бокс со строкой напротив которой он находится.Как сделать так чтобы при клике на чек бокс выбиралась эта строка а при нажатии на редактировать, выводилась бы для редактирования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Есть код таблицы:

```html
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"></th>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Фио клиента</th>
    <th>Дата</th>
    <th>Время</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($result as $res) {
$db->where ('id', $res['dentist_id']);
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td><?php echo $res['visitors_fio']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['visit_date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['visit_time']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<label for=chk-id>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал сделать следующее:

1. Для начала дайте `<input type="checkbox">` атрибуты `value` с `id` записи и класс к примеру `checkbox` для удобства, но это не обязательно, в своем коде для примера я буду использовать его как селектор.
2. Тегу `<tr>` тоже можете дать класс `selected` для визуального показа что блок выделен, но это не обязательно.
3. Кнопке `Редактировать` дайте класс `edit-btn` или любой другой, но тогда измените JS.
4. И самое главное это JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
        //Эта функция отвечает за то, что при клике на чек давать tr class selected или убирать
        $('table').on('click', '.checkbox', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
        });

        //Когда вы выбрали чек и нажмете редактировать то будет редирект на странице редактирования
        $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function() {
            var $checkbox = $('table').find('.checkbox:checked:first');
            if ($checkbox.length) {
                var id = $checkbox.val();
                alert('Сейчас будет редирект на редактирование записи с ID:' + id);
                window.location.replace('/update/' + id);
            }
            else {
                alert('Не выбрана колонка для редактирования');
            }
        });
    });
```

Но есть один недочет, скрипт перед первую колонку где установлен чекбок, если выбирать будете несколько то тут надо или убирать с остальных и оставлять только на одном, или выдавать предупреждение, хотя это не очень, или оставьте как есть.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите [ссылку](http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp) по кастомизации чекбоксов, там ясно как связать строку и чекбокс.

```css
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label
{
  
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
   background:red;
 
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}






/* Useless styles, just for demo design */

body {
  font-family: "Open sans", "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  margin: 5px 0 2em;
  color: #aaa;
}
form {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.txtcenter {
  margin-top: 4em;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}
.copy {
 margin-top: 2em; 
}
.copy a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #4778d9;
}
```

```html
  <form action="#">
      <p>
       <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
      <label for="test1">Red</label>
      </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Текст вопроса прочитайте

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.